# How can we generate the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi file using the wsejbdeploy ant task

Tags: ant

Is it possible to generate the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi file using the wsejbdeploy ant task? How can we generate the same using maven? Tried using was6-maven-plugin but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the [wsDefaultBindings](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/api/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/package-summary.html) task ([usage should be similar to these example WAS 6.1 Ant scripts](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/08/ant-automated-deployment-to-websphere.html)).

I have not tried automating this with Maven, but I suspect more information than "it didn't work" would be required to diagnose the problem.